# Returning the href content which the user has clicked on

Tags: ms-access, webbrowser-control

I am trying to display daily appointment information in MS Access.  I thought the best way to do this dynamically would be building a table in an HTML file, with a link to each appointment contained in an href, and displaying it in an MS Access web browser. The problem arises when the user wants to click on a specific appointment.  How can MS Access retrieve the href information the user has clicked on?

The HTML would read like this

```html
<td class="Event"><div class="clickable"><a href= '#N10~20190327~9:00:00 AM'> </a></div></td>
```

Comment: You _can_ inject javascript in the document that modifies the DOM after a click, and then read back the modified document. However, this seems like doing it wrong. You should try just using form controls, instead of concocting some complicated HTML+Access+VBA+JS way to figure it out.

Comment: Where is appointment data stored? If not Access tables, where?

Comment: the data is stored in tables, then a query brings it together for a day and then that is output to html and displayed in the Access WebBroswer control.

Comment: To add when I right click one of the cells off the html table and click "Copy Shortcut" i can see the string I am looking for. file:///C:/Path/Calendar_Output.html#N10~20190327~2:30:00 PM.  If I have the string after the # then I can open a form for the user to input an appointment.  The closest I have got is using the WebBrowser0.LocationURL but this only gives the local location of the file and the not the string in the h ref.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just found out that the WebBrowser0.LocationURL used in the BeforeNavigate event will pick up the file path and the href content.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DW40  If you found an answer yourself, the best thing to do is post it as an answer, not a comment.  (It is okay for the original poster to answer the question.)  Doing so also gives you opportunity for more reputation points.  Otherwise the question goes officially unanswered on SO and does not help anyone else.

Comment: I was curious as to why this approach and not just link to Outlook Calendar. So I tested link and discovered a bunch of historical junk saved in Calendar that derived from emails, like "Package from Amazon". Annoying.

Comment: However, still not clear to me why this approach and not just a form to display table data.